# Data handling of HashMultimap

Tags: java, java-stream, guava, multimap

I have a HashMultimap

`Multimap<String, String> map = HashMultimap.create();`

The data I put into the map is

```
map.put("cpu", "i9");
map.put("hang", "MSI");
map.put("hang", "DELL");
map.put("hang", "DELL");
map.put("cpu", "i5");
map.put("hang", "HP");
map.put("cpu", "i7");
```

I have a stream

```
String joinString = map.entries().stream().map(e -> e.getKey() + "=" + e.getValue()).collect(Collectors.joining(" OR "));
```

I need the output to be

> (hang=HP OR hang=MSI OR hang=DELL) **AND** (cpu=i9 OR cpu=i5 OR cpu=i7)

I need an `AND` in between the keys. How can I do that?

Comment: "**Thank you very much for your instructions**" - Here are my instructions. 1) Read the javadoc for the `Joiner` class. 2) If you can't figure out how to do this with streams, use classic Java instead; e.g. a loop, `StringBuilder.append` and so on.  3) Please don't treat StackOverflow as a free code writing service.  Show us your (genuine) attempt at solving the problem in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Map view:

```
String joined = map.asMap()
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .map(e -> e.getValue()
                .stream()
                .map(v -> e.getKey() + "=" + v)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" OR ", "(", ")")))
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" AND "));
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course schmosel beat me, but here a slightly different api/usage:

```java
String joined = map.keySet() // keySet() instead of asMap()
  .stream().map(k
    -> String.format( // string.format instead of concatenation ;)
        "(%s)",
        map.get(k).stream() // map.get(k) instead of e.getValue()
            .map(v
                -> String.format("%s=%s", k, v))
            .collect(Collectors.joining(" OR "))
       )
  ).collect(Collectors.joining(" AND "));
```